# Json распарсить

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Возник вопрос насчет разбора JSON. Пока что я получаю данные в виде строки. Я бы хотел распарсить в класс через `Gson`. Дело в том что название заголовка `179746` меняется. Оно может принимать другое имя, все остальное не меняется. Использую для генерации класса [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) , ну если у нас название заголовка становится `10000`, то класс сразу становится не используемым

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "meta": {
    "count": 1
  },
  "data": {
    "179746": {
      "leader_id": 3239400
    }
  }
}
```

Может можно как-то убрать тут 179746, и подставить общий параметр, я не знаю как делать.

```
  public class Data {

@SerializedName("179746")
@Expose
private com.example._179746 _179746;

public com.example._179746 get179746() {
return _179746;
}

public void set179746(com.example._179746 _179746) {
this._179746 = _179746;
}
```

Пока что я делаю так

```
  jsonObject = new JSONObject(getResponse);
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

                JSONObject json = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("179746");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если бы jsonschema2pojo не использовали, количество вопросов связанных с Gson на SO резко бы сократилось вдвое. На это есть следующие причины:

- автоматические генераторы весьма наивно "сочиняют" маппинги, не учитывая динамических структур данных типа `List`, `Map` и т.д.;
- они совсем плохо дружат с дженериками;
- они часто не делают даже минимального "опережающего" анализа, чтобы определить, что то или иное поле просто могут иметь разные типы (т.е. могут быть полиморфны -- следствие из предыдущей претензии);
- не уверен на счёт именно того сервиса, но, по крайней мере, настройки по умолчанию генерируют весьма много шума.

Кроме того, в Gson не существует `JSON***` -- типов с заглавными "JSON" в имени. Это из org.json, в то время как в Gson всегда -- `Json***`. Дальше, если вы уж и собрались использовать маппинги, их  можно использовать почти во всех случаях, и не смешивать их с сущностями, которые представляют JSON-объекты в памяти в виде древовидных структур (т.е., всё семейство `JsonElement`). Ещё: для объектов с динамическими именами в Gson существует родная поддержка `Map<K,V>` (впрочем, это справедливо и  для Java, поскольку количество имён не известно заранее на этапе компиляции).

Резюмируя вышесказанное, в этом случае нужно просто написать правильные маппинги.

```java
final class Response<T> {

    final String status = null;
    final Meta meta = null;
    final T data = null;

}
```

```java
final class Meta {

    final int count = Integer.valueOf(0);

}
```

```java
final class Leader {

    @SerializedName("leader_id")
    final int leaderId = Integer.valueOf(0);

}
```

Чем это отличается от того, что генерирует тот сервис:

- более совершенная поддержка полиморфности (`Response<T>`);
- не делается предположений о "зашитых" именах;
- здесь почти нет `@SerializedName` и нет `@Expose` -- с одной стороны это спорно и противоречит "явному, которое лучше неявного"; с другой -- меньше шума;
- это примитивные "data bags" и здесь нет аксессоров (`set***`/`get***`) -- объекты, предназначенные исключительно для переноса данных между компонентами системы (DTO) и которые должны использоваться исключительно сопутствующими компонентами могут опускать это требование хорошего тона, поскольку здесь и инкапсулировать-то нечего;
- пример JSON-документа в вопросе похож на ответ от сервиса, поэтому поля маппингов можно оградить от изменений, сделав их `final` -- изменяться же не должно (Gson отлично справляется с классами без конструкторов и умеет изменять `final`-поля во время исполнения; исключение из такого "паттерна": примитивным типам как `int` не могут присваиватся значения по-умолчанию типа `= 0`, потому что компилятор просто заинлайнит это значения, и у Gson не будет возможности изменить поле (точнее, места, в которые эта константа заинлайнена) -- поэтому `Integer.valueOf(0)` является своего рода хаком, чтобы ослепить компилятор).

Пример использования:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

private static final Type leaderMapResponseType = new TypeToken<Response<Map<Integer, Leader>>>() {
}.getType();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q660527.class, "response.json") ) {
        final Response<Map<Integer, Leader>> response = gson.fromJson(reader, leaderMapResponseType);
        System.out.println(response.status);
        System.out.println(response.meta.count);
        for ( final Entry<Integer, Leader> e : response.data.entrySet() ) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " => " + e.getValue().leaderId);
        }
    }
}
```

Инстансы `Gson` и `Type` (по крайней мере те, что порождены с использованием `TypeToken<T>`) могут считаться иммутабельными и потокобезопасными, поэтому их можно закешировать, не прибегая к повторному созданию экземпляров с теми же характеристиками. Пару слов о том, что такое "type token"-ы. В Java из-за специфики реализации дженериков не существует возможности написать `Response<Map<String,Leader>>.class`, потому что `Class<T>` не содержат информации об *актуальной* параметризации за исключением параметризации родительского класса при наследовании. Возможно, было б очень круто, если бы в Java можно было создавать ad-hoc реализации `Type`/`ParameterizedType` примерно как `Response<Map<String,Leader>>.type`, но увы. Как Gson решает эту проблему? Как я сказал выше, параметризация сохраняется при наследовании, поэтому Gson требует хотя бы анонимной реализации класса `TypeToken<T>`. При создании экземпляра `TypeToken<T>` Gson имеет достаточно информации о том, как параметризирован `Response<T>`, и его вызов `getType()` возвращает уже проанализированную информацию о *параметризированном типе*, а не просто о классе. Это эквивалентно ручной реализации `ParameterizedType`, но с помощью предыдущего механизма запись немножко короче и красивее. И да: "type token"-ы не нужны, если например информация о параметризации уже доступна, например, из типа поля в каком-нибудь классе (т.е., обычный `private final Map<String, Float> map;` уже содержит достаточно информации о типе (класс по прежнему -- просто `Map`)).

Результат вывода:

> ok
>   1
>   179746 => 3239400

Answer (score 1):

Может вам сначала получить название через строку и потом его использовать

```
int startIndex = getResponse.indexOf("\"data\": {")+9;
int endIndex = getResponse.indexOf("\": {", startIndex);
String nameAfterData = getResponse.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
```

и потом просто использовать имя JSON объекта пр парсинге?